# Plot with confidence intervals from 1D data?

Tags: r, statistics

If all my data is a long row of comma separated values (duration times), then R can give me a lot of info by

```
summary(dat)
```

**Question**

Can R also make a plot of the data with confidence intervals?

Comment: This may depend on what population parameter you want confidence intervals for, whether you bootstrap it or have an assumption about the underlying distribution of your data and so on.

Comment: Is all you have a vector of duration times? No explanatory variables? Then all you can probably do is a mean and a variance (okay, skewness and kurtosis and all that as well). Confidence intervals for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first google match stated, you can try doing as:

```
n<-50
x<-sample(40:70,n,rep=T)
y<-.7*x+rnorm(n,sd=5)
plot(x,y,xlim=c(20,90),ylim=c(0,80))
mylm<-lm(y~x)
abline(mylm,col="red")
newx<-seq(20,90)
prd<-predict(mylm,newdata=data.frame(x=newx),interval = c("confidence"), 
level = 0.90,type="response")
lines(newx,prd[,2],col="red",lty=2)
lines(newx,prd[,3],col="red",lty=2)
```

Of course it is one of possibilities
Another example would be:

```
x <- rnorm(15)
y <- x + rnorm(15)
new <- data.frame(x = seq(-3, 3, 0.5))

pred.w.clim <- predict(lm(y ~ x), new, interval="confidence")


# Just create a blank plot region with axes first. We'll add to this
plot(range(new$x), range(pred.w.clim), type = "n", ann = FALSE)


# For convenience
CI.U <- pred.w.clim[, "upr"]
CI.L <- pred.w.clim[, "lwr"]

# Create a 'loop' around the x values. Add values to 'close' the loop
X.Vec <- c(new$x, tail(new$x, 1), rev(new$x), new$x[1])

# Same for y values
Y.Vec <- c(CI.L, tail(CI.U, 1), rev(CI.U), CI.L[1])

# Use polygon() to create the enclosed shading area
# We are 'tracing' around the perimeter as created above
polygon(X.Vec, Y.Vec, col = "grey", border = NA)


# Use matlines() to plot the fitted line and CI's
# Add after the polygon above so the lines are visible
matlines(new$x, pred.w.clim, lty = c(1, 2, 2), type = "l", col =  
c("black", "red", "red"))
```

[Example 1](http://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-November/146285.html)

[Example 2](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/plotting-confidence-intervals-td897422.html)

Comment: Any chance of an explanation of how this answers the question? We can't even make sense of the question, and you've got x's and y's and all sorts of things. You might be some kind of psychic...

Comment: the question is
"Can R also make a plot of the data with confidence intervals?" as stated in OP's post; so the answer is "yes", how it can be done? the examples is provided (Example 1, Example 2) - the OP's problem is how to modify it to suit her needs; I thought, and as the OP accepted answer showed that this was the meaning of the question, that the OP wanted to know if (and if yes - how) to draw the CI with R

Comment: It would be nice if the OP refined the question to state all this. All we have for evidence is a green tick. "A plot of the data" could just as well be a histogram and "confidence intervals" be 95% quantiles marked on it. You've assumed a lot. Poor question is still poor.

Comment: Yes it's true - assumption is the draw force of the progress ;), but still I think people have to have right to ask not specific questions - maybe they'd have to be tagged as "howto"?

Comment: They have that right, but they also have the responsibility to improve their questions to make SO a better place. Its not all about them.

Comment: Agree, so you can say my answer was a lucky guess :)